# What is the difference between Environment.CurrentDirectory and Directory.GetCurrentDirectory?

Tags: c#, .net

In .NET what is the difference between:

- `Environment.CurrentDirectory`
- `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`?

Of course, `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is a property which can be set and obtained.

Are there any other differences?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As David says: they do the same thing. Internally, when getting `Environment.CurrentDirectory` it will call `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` and when setting `Environment.CurrentDirectory` it will call `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory`.

Just pick a favorite and go with it.

Answer (score 31):

As per other answers, there is no difference - the implemenetation of `Environment.CurrentDirectory` delegates to the `Get` and `Set` methods in `Directory`.

There's an interesting stylistic API-design question that raises - why did the designers of `Environment` feel that a regular property was appropriate, whereas the designers of `Directory` preferred explicit `Get` and `Set` methods?

The Framework Design Guidelines book has a fair amount to say about choosing properties versus methods, some of which is [available online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx). The most relevant parts seem to me to be (with my emphases):

> A rule of thumb is that methods should
> represent actions and properties
> should represent data. *Properties are
> preferred over methods **if everything
> else is equal***
>
> ...
>
> - CONSIDER using a property, if the member represents a logical attribute
>   of the type
>
> ...
>
> - DO use a method, rather than a property, in the following situations:
>
>   - The operation is orders of magnitude slower than a field access
>     would be

All things considered my opinion is that explicit `Get` and `Set` **methods** better represent what is going on here.

Comment: +1 I don't often vote in Q&A's that I am also posting in, but referring do the Framework Design Guidelines is worth an upvote. I also agree with your conclusion.

Comment: I think it is more a logical difference that is the cause of this. It is a natural property in the Environment context, but in Directory, it is more a "directory related" utility function.

Comment: Consistency with the rest of the class was probably a factor too.  Back in v1.1 nearly all members of Environment were properties returning simple, often fixed, strings.  By contrast nearly all the members of Directory are expensive operations accessing the file system.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no other differences.

Answer (score 1):

Directory.SetCurrentDirectory throws no fewer than 7 exceptions, so checking up on all the things that could go wrong could be time-consuming. The method therefore presumably complies with

"DO use a method, rather than a property, in the following situations:

```
The operation is orders of magnitude slower than a field access would be"
```

Even GetCurrentDirectory has 2 potential exceptions. Across a network and/or with a large number of subdirectories to navigate these could potentially take seconds instead of milliseconds in the worst case.

Answer (score -2):

`public static string GetCurrentDirectory ();`
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,4de7d0d0c291277b

`public static string CurrentDirectory { get; set; }`
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs,b64586ead0df012b

Although the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` called `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`, I still prefer to use `Environment.CurrentDirectory`, since it's a static property, can response faster.

Comment: "I'm not sure the implementation" the source code is online (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime), you could go and check before speculating about which is actually quicker.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31419673)