# Not getting current working directory in Release Mode?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get the current working directory of my exe. `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` not returning working directory of the exe when deploying the application.

What is the way to get current working directory?

Comment: I doubt the function is broken. So the working directory *isn't* the one you expected, for whatever reason. How are you deploying the application, how is it being started, what directory did you *expect* the current directory to be, and what directory is it *actually*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi
       try `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Comment: @jgauffin:I used to use Environment.CurrentDirectory to get the working directory for application and it seems to be working in Dev environment,but when I was creating a  window service and intalled it 'Environment.CurrentDirectory' returned the path of the system32 folder.So that why started using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory which I think is safe.

Comment: `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is the directory that the application was started in. All applications can be started from anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

<del>try:</del>

<del>`var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory`</del>

<del>or:</del>

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: The first one is the same as what the OP is trying, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164756/what-is-the-difference-between-environment-currentdirectory-and-directory-getcurr